# Optaplanner - NullPointerException when creating jar file

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, optaplanner

My program works fine from my IDE (IntelliJ) but for some reason, when I try to create a jar file I get following error when I run the program from a terminal:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:461)
>
> org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
>
> org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
>
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:57)
>
> org.optaplanner.EmployeeRoster.main(EmployeeRoster.java:31)

This is my line 31 in EmployeeRoster:

```
Solver solver = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SOLVER_CONFIG_XML).buildSolver();
```

SOLVER_CONFIG_XML is a String containing my path for my XML solver-config,
it looks like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
 <solutionClass>org.optaplanner.solver.Roster</solutionClass>
 <entityClass>org.optaplanner.domain.Assignment</entityClass>
 <scoreDirectorFactory>
  <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/solver/employeeShiftsScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
 </scoreDirectorFactory>
 <localSearch>
  <termination>
   <secondsSpentLimit>5</secondsSpentLimit>
   <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0medium/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
  </termination>
  <!--<termination>
   <unimprovedStepCountLimit>5</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
  </termination>-->
  <acceptor>
   <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
  </acceptor>
  <forager>
   <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
  </forager>
 </localSearch>
</solver>
```

Also here's my pom.xml file if that should be relevant:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.btrg.dfb</groupId>
<artifactId>optaplanner</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
        <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.avalin.optaplanner.EmployeeRoster</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I deducted that its when I get to .buildSolver(), the nullpointer occurs :/ it does find the XML file both in the ide and in the terminal, but for some reason only in the terminal, the buildSolver() returns null

Comment: Sounds like a kie or drools jar is missing from the classpath?

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey! You were right, I just wrote the drools-core.jar, drools-compiler.jar the kie-api.jar and kie-internal.jar into my manifest file. At first it didn't work as I had used commas to separate them from each other but when I fixed that it worked flawlessly. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: [Related jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-885)

Comment: [Related jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1761) which links to 2 other similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the issue had to deal with how I wanted to run the jar (***java -jar***), and consequently how I built the jar. The NullPointerException arose when I upgraded to ***optaplanner-core/7.4.1*** from ***6.4.0***. This issue was not present back when I was still using 6.4.0.

Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(ResourceFactory.java:66)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getResource(AbstractKieModule.java:299)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:264)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:259)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:243)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:74)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:250)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:218)
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:176)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:503)

The following is a **temporary workaround** I did to resolve the NullPointerException and just get the application to run.

1. Use IntelliJ's gradle to build one big jar with all dependencies.
2. Unzip the jar, for example, to ***unzippedJar/*** directory.
3. Modify ***unzippedJar/META-INF/kie.conf***
4. Rejar the files.
5. Run the jar with java.

### Step 1. Building the jar

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'org.optaplanner', name: 'optaplanner-core', version:'7.4.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.optaplanner', name: 'optaplanner-benchmark', version:'7.4.1.Final'
    ...
}
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Self contained jar with all dependencies',
        'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Main-Class': 'path.to.class.with.main.method'
    }
    baseName = 'fatJar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

### Step 2. Unzip

`unzip fatJar.jar -d unzippedJar/`

### Step 3. Modify kie.conf

The "fatJar" task flattened the dependencies - duplicate file names are allowed in the jar. This resulted in four *unzippedJar/META-INF/kie.conf* files, only one of which was used. Regardless of whichever kie.conf file was used, this was my final kie.conf.

```
    org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers = +org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.kie.KieSolverAssemblerService
    org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers = org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl
    org.kie.api.internal.runtime.KieRuntimes = org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl
    org.kie.api.internal.weaver.KieWeavers = org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl
    org.kie.api.internal.runtime.beliefs.KieBeliefs = org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl
    org.kie.api.io.KieResources = org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl
    org.kie.api.marshalling.KieMarshallers = org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl
    org.kie.api.concurrent.KieExecutors = org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl
    org.kie.api.KieServices = org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl
    org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService = org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl
```

### Step 4. Rejar

For whatever reason, specifying the MANIFEST.MF file did nothing for me, hence I left it out.

`jar cf rejard.jar .`

### Step 5. Run the jar

`java -cp rejard.jar path.to.class.with.main.method`

Comment: This worked for me in Optaplanner 7.8.0.Final, though I had to specify the manifest file when re`jar`ing, like this: `jar cfm rejard.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .`. Then I can run the jar file normally with `java -jar rejard.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Following @Arturo W's answer, I can suggest another fix using [maven's
assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to
make a fat jar.

As stated in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html):

> "If two or more elements (e.g., file, fileSet) select different sources for
>   the same file for archiving, only one of the source files will be archived.
>   [...] The order of the phases is as follows: 1) FileItem 2) FileSets
>   3) ModuleSet 4) DependencySet and 5) Repository elements."

`META-INF/kie.conf` is provided in `org.optaplanner.core`'s archive, hence
maven packages optaplanner's version over the custom one define in your
repository.

To include it, we exclude all `META-INF/kie.conf` files during unpackaging
and manually copy our version using the [`<file></file>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file)
option in a custom descriptor file.

Here's how we do it:

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ... -->

            <!-- fat jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.veryseriouscompany.veryseriousproject.app.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- ... -->
```

To fix the inclusion of `kie.conf`, we'll have to write a custom descriptor,
defined in `src/assembly/distribution.xml`. We start from a predefined
descriptor:
[jar-with-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html).
That's a good starting point.

#### src/assembly/distribution.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>epigno-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <!-- Exclude all META-INF/kie.conf during unpacking -->
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/kie.conf</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <!-- Manually copy your custom kie configuration file from your repository. -->
            <!-- Please replace this path by whatever path is relevant for your project. -->
            <source>src/main/resources/META-INF/kie.conf</source>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

When you are finished, run

```
mvn package
```

Hopefully, this will package the correct `kie.conf` in your fat jar!