# optaplanner nullpointerexception ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig when packaged as jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar, optaplanner

I have made a slightly modified version of the MeetingScheduling example in optaplanner-distribution-7.2.0.Final it runs fine in IntelliJ 2017.2  When I build a jar out of it then I get the following exception.  I am using Java 1.8

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:461)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:57)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolver(CommonApp.java:108)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:102)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:89)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:80)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.meetingscheduling3.app.MeetingScheduling3App.main(MeetingScheduling3App.java:31)
```

Are there more detailed instructions on how to make a jar from an optaplanner distribution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. How are you building your JAR?

Comment: Might be [a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199392/optaplanner-nullpointerexception-when-creating-jar-file).

Comment: [Related jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-885)

Comment: [Related jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1761) which links to 2 other similar questions.